# input() function prevents new multiprocessing process to start when run through PyCharm

Tags: python, multithreading, input, multiprocessing

I have a simple program (below) which does not behave as I expected when 
I run it through PyCharm. It behaves as expected when run through command prompt.

It is a program that spawns a new process, but after that, reads input from user using `input()` function. The problem is that when I use this function, the process does not start until the input is entered.

The problem does not occur when I use `threading` module instead and create a new thread. But I need to use `multiprocessing` module since I initiate GUI in the spawned process which creates other problems if not run in a separate process instead of just a new thread.

One workaround I found is to `sleep()` after calling `start()`, but it feels like an ugly workaround which might fail depending on CPU power if I don't wait long enough for the GUI to initiate.

So I want to know why this problem occurs and if there is an elegant way to solve it instead of `sleep()`?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


def my_func():
    print("The process has started.")


def main():
    p = mp.Process(target=my_func)
    p.start()

    # If we uncomment this, process will start as expected. If commented out, it will wait for input.
    # time.sleep(1)

    # Things I want to do while the process is on-going like getting an input from user and processing the input.
    print(input("Please input something:"))

    # wait for the window to be closed
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I use Windows 10, PyCharm 2019.1, Python 3.6.8, 64-bit

Comment: Interesting! Doesn't happen on Linux. Does `sleep(0)` work?

Comment: sleep(0) does not work. But I just discovered, the problem only occurs when I run it through PyCharm. When I run it on command prompt, it does not happen. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I cannot replicate this issue, but you could try with wrapping your `input`-handling in an extra thread.

Answer (score 0):

Not happening on Linux. Even changing the multiprocessing `set_start_method` to `spawn`.

Can you paste some screenshots or logs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just discovered that it happens when I run the program through PyCharm. It works as expected when run through command prompt. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally fix this by checking the "Emulate terminal in output console" option in the run configuration.